# How to get database connection object

Tags: database-connection, liferay, liferay-6

I would like to get `database connection object` in portlet environment. So, what is java class name which provide the connection object ?

(i don't use `servicebuilder` because of my own reasons).

Thank for all suggestions !

Comment: I havent tried or done this anytime. But just a thought,  DBFactoryUtil.java could be useful.

Comment: @Pankaj Kathiriya Thank for your reply, but i can not get Connection, you can see at http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/

Comment: Well, you could probably use (never really tried, but this thing is used during the upgrade process) `DBFactoryUtil.getDB()` method in order to obtain the current DB instance, and then call the `runSQL` method. Or you can get the JDBC Connection... it depends on what you have to do.

Comment: @Andrea Di Giorgi Does this connection inherit pooling ?

Comment: @Andrea Di Giorgi How can i get result when SQL is executed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this class in `com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.jdbc` package:

```
DataAccess.getConnection()
```

Comment: Thank, i will try in next day :)